# var vm = this, making $http request twice

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is my controller code:

```
.controller('TransitCtrl', function ($ionicPlatform, $scope, $state, $q, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $timeout, $http, design, config) {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
    var vm = this;
    vm.userImg = design.user_img;

    vm.isGetStarted = false;
    vm.getPV = true;
    vm.getPL = false;
    vm.showWelcome = false;
    var counter = 1;
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){  
        $timeout( function(){
             var userDataStageFirst = {
              url: config.baseURL + 'userDataStageFirst',
              dataServer: {
                serverTaskRequest: counter
              }
            }
            var url = userDataStageFirst.url;
            var dataServer = userDataStageFirst.dataServer;
            $http.post(url, dataServer).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data)
              })
              .error(function () {
                alert("error");
              });
        }, 1000 ); 
     });
  })
```

And here is this app.js

```
.state('app.transit', {
      url: '/transit',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/transit.html',
          controller: 'TransitCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

and My html page

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" ng-controller="TransitCtrl as vm">
  <ion-content>
      hello world
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When I use `$scope` in place of `vm` its working perfectly good, but when I use `vm`, it sends 2 `$http` request to the server. Not being able to understand `this` concept here.

Comment: remove `ng-controller="TransitCtrl as vm"` from template and add ` controller: 'TransitCtrl as vm'` to state

Comment: Tried this but now there is no `$http` request at all.

Comment: It says 502 Bad Gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove `ng-controller="TransitCtrl as vm"` from template.

and change to this

```
state('app.transit', {
  url: '/transit',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/transit.html',
      controller: 'TransitCtrl as vm'
    }
  }
})
```